# Caching Static Assets in Github Pages

Tags: caching, github-pages, browser-cache, image-caching

I am trying to cache static assets like images for my website in github pages - so that they are not requested again and again.

I've noticed in some other [questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119286/caching-assets-in-website-served-from-github-pages) that github pages by default add Cache-Control to max-age=600

So I switched to removing local references and using s3 based url's with a max age set of large value - and referencing those links instead of relative urls

[image]

-> But I saw that cache-control is getting set to no-cache in the request headers -> is it because of this that the image is getting requested again and again ?

[image]

I've tried preloading the images and all that via javascript - but it's not helping and the image is getting requested again - and not getting cached at all.

I am not able to make at what layer - javascript, AWS or Github pages has the issue.

Comment: It's certainly the case that using `no-cache` in the request header can cause this. The question is who or what is setting that. Make sure you're not getting thrown off by debugging tools (for example, some developer tools might default to disabling cache and implement that by using that directive).